# \autocap failing on Ibidem (Biblatex Verbose style)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I can't get my Ibidem go uppercase when needed.

I tried the \autocap, without success:

```
MWE:

% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !BIB program = biber
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TeX TS-program = xelatexmk

\begin{filecontents}{archivio.bib}

@collection{Bre:Mo2,
    Title = {Questo è il titolo con 2 curatori},
    Address = {Bari},
    Editor = {John Smith AND James Brown},
    Publisher = {Laterza},
    Year = {1998}}  

\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[A4, 11pt, twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}                        
    \setmainlanguage{italian}

\usepackage{xpatch}     
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,            
            language=italian,
            ibidpage=true,
        ]{biblatex} 

\NewBibliographyString{ibidemloccit,ibidemnoloccit}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext{%
    \bibhyperlink{cite\csuse{cbx@lastcite@\thefield{entrykey}}}{%
      \ifloccit
        {\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidemloccit}%
         \global\toggletrue{cbx:loccit}}
        {\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidemnoloccit}}}}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{ibidemloccit={\mkbibemph{\autocap{i}bidem}}}

\addbibresource{archivio.bib}  


\begin{document}

I just want the “Ibidem" go on autocap. So after the fullstop the “I” must be uppercase:\\

\cite[178-179]{Bre:Mo2}
\vspace*{2ex}

And now fullstop. \cite[178-179]{Bre:Mo2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\autocap` works as intended in your example, but it alone can't help here.

The problem is that **`biblatex` can not detect preceding punctuation**. The `\cite` simply does not know that it comes after a period or rather *at the beginning of a new sentence*. If you want to start a sentence with a citation, you should use the capitalised form `\Cite` instead of `\cite` (`\Autocite` instead of `\autocite` etc. etc.). It is not possible to automatically detect previous punctuation reliably without larger changes to the LaTeX setup.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{italian}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,
            ibidpage=true,
        ]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{ibidemloccit,ibidemnoloccit}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext{%
    \bibhyperlink{cite\csuse{cbx@lastcite@\thefield{entrykey}}}{%
      \ifloccit
        {\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidemloccit}%
         \global\toggletrue{cbx:loccit}}
        {\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidemnoloccit}}}}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{ibidemloccit={\mkbibemph{\autocap{i}bidem}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
I just want the “Ibidem" go on autocap. So after the fullstop the “I” must be uppercase:

\cite[178-179]{sigfridsson}

And now fullstop. \Cite[178-179]{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

[image: And now fullstop. Ibidem]